# Protecting components from catastrophic age-related battery failure

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry, corrosion

As someone who does a lot of restoration work on old electronic devices of all kinds, finding old, leaking batteries well beyond their use-by date is common. Finding that the battery leak has destroyed numerous traces or other components on a packed PCB is also common.

[image: Corroded barrel battery]

The first step taken when addressing a device like this is to remove the battery before it can do any more damage, neutralize whatever caustic gunk is still on the board, and then remove the debris and test before installing a compatible battery.

However, this is prolonging the inevitable. The new battery will eventually fail in the same way, with its seals giving way and releasing electrolyte into the surroundings, possibly years in the future.

Many of the devices this is happening to will sit without being energized for a long time, so regular checking of the battery is not feasible.

**My question is: is there some "standard" method you could use to protect the PCB from this failure case when, not if, it happens?**

One thing I've seen done is wiring the battery to the PCB terminals and placing the actual cell far away from the board, and that is definitely viable. Still, I'm looking for more options, ideally, a canonical option, if one is known.

Comment: Mount the batteries off-board using extension wires.

Comment: I've seen little plastic pans to catch the goo, to at least contain it. I like the idea of wiring it remote even more. Better still, is adding room for a second battery, for the moment of changing them. I rigged up something like this for employer's HAAS CNC machine, which would otherwise wipe out its calibrations when the battery went (was hard to believe around year 2010) ... the HAAS service guys liked it and I'm told they copied it, tho hopefully they don't need batteries any more, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer the same advice that manufacturers of these devices put in their manuals: if the device is not to be used for a prolonged period, remove the batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Try brushing some silicone dielectric grease all over both terminals. Then wait and see. The silicone will act as a physical barrier and possibly as a chemical neutralizer. It will do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some kind of plastic tube so the leakage has farther to go before reaching the circuit board, and wires coming out of the tube.  Give it somewhere else to accumulate and dry out.  Maybe a shrinkwrap tube shrunk a little at the ends to leave a catch-pocket space.  Maybe something absorbent in that pocket, like cardboard.